# Use secured WMS service from ArcGIS in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-server, authentication

I need to add some WMS services from token protected ArcGIS server to GeoServer.

I added WMS store and in end of "Capabilities URL" I added token param `&token=xxx` and got layer list. After publishing in layer preview I am getting 499 error, because when GeoServer asks tiles from ArcGIS it is not using token.

Has anyone had a similar situation?

Comment: I did not, but my guess is that ArcGis fails to report the token in the backlinks to GetMap/GetFeatureInfo operations found in the capabilities document, making the token parameter an effective vendor option that the client has to be aware of.